# JavaScript onChange Event to use current row values only

Tags: javascript, html, json

An extension of my previous calculators, its now time to look at the onChange or addEventListener functions to run my code without using the submit buttons.

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I can have the event fire once either the 'H' or 'Extra Room Factor' fields have been changed. I only want the row that is being edited / changed to fire the event, not the entire table. I am trying to figure out how I can 'find' which row / cell is calling the function and then use it in the script to get the other values required.

The script uses JSON to get data which determines how the table is set out.

The code should get the values from L, W and H and multiply them together. It should then multiply the Extra Room Factor and write the result into the 'Total Room M3' field.

(No Rep to post images) [image: screenshot]

Uh, I have all my code in a fiddle but the current code relies on JSON to get the details. I can't post the fiddle link due to low rep!

`jsfiddle`[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mkpadL8u/)

[JSON File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7559387/data.json)
Thanks!

```js
function init() {

 var url = "http://localhost/javascript/comcool/working/data.json";
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open("GET", url);
 request.send(null);

 request.onload = function () {
  if (request.status === 200) {
   result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   drawMainTable();
   drawTable2();
   drawTable3();
  }
 rooms = result.numberOfRooms;
 }; 
}

function drawMainTable() {
 
 var div = document.getElementById("calc");
 
 var drawTable = document.createElement("table");
  drawTable.id = "calcTable";
  drawTable.className = "tg";
  div.appendChild(drawTable);
  
 var table = document.getElementById("calcTable");

  //Draw Location Field
  for ( var i = 0; i < result.locations.length ; i++ ) {
   if ( result.locations[i].name !== null) {
    var locations = document.getElementById("location");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = result.locations[i].name;
    option.text = result.locations[i].name;
    locations.appendChild(option);
   }
  }
  
  //Create Head Elements
  for ( var i = 0; i < result.titles.length; i++ ) {
  var createHead = document.createElement("th");
   createHead.innerHTML = result.titles[i].name;
   table.appendChild(createHead);
   }
   
  //Create Row Elements
  for ( var i = 0; i < result.numberOfRooms ; i++ ) {
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
 
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var roomInput = document.createElement("input");
            roomInput.type = "text";
            roomInput.id = "R" + i + "Name";
            cell1.appendChild(roomInput);
 
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var lInput = document.createElement("input");
            lInput.type = "number";
            lInput.id = "R" + i + "L";
   lInput.className = "smallInput";
            cell2.appendChild(lInput);
 
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var wInput = document.createElement("input");
            wInput.type = "number";
            wInput.id = "R" + i + "W";
   wInput.className = "smallInput";
            cell3.appendChild(wInput);
   
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var hInput = document.createElement("input");
            hInput.type = "number";
            hInput.id = "R" + i + "H";
   hInput.onchange = calculateRoomM3;
   hInput.className = "smallInput";
            cell4.appendChild(hInput);

   var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var extraRoomFactorInput = document.createElement("input");
            extraRoomFactorInput.type = "number";
            extraRoomFactorInput.id = "R" + i + "Factor";
   extraRoomFactorInput.value = "1.0";
   extraRoomFactorInput.step = "0.1";
   extraRoomFactorInput.min = "1.0";
   extraRoomFactorInput.max = "1.3";
            cell5.appendChild(extraRoomFactorInput);
   
   var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var m3Output = document.createElement("output");
            m3Output.id = "R" + i + "M3Total";
            cell6.appendChild(m3Output);
   
   var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            var suggDia = document.createElement("output");
            suggDia.id = "R" + i + "Dia";
            cell7.appendChild(suggDia);
   
   var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            var outSize = document.createElement("select");
            outSize.id = "R" + i + "OutletSize";
            cell8.appendChild(outSize);
  
    for ( var x = 0; x < result.ductInfo.length ; x++ ) {
     if ( result.ductInfo[x].ventSize != "nil") {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = result.ductInfo[x].ventSize;
      option.text = result.ductInfo[x].ventSize;
      outSize.appendChild(option);
     }
    }
   
   var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
            var ductDia = document.createElement("output");
            ductDia.id = "R" + i + "DuctSize";
            cell9.appendChild(ductDia);
  } 

}

function drawTable2() {
 
 var p = document.getElementById("total");
 
 var table = document.createElement("Table");
  table.id = "totalTable";
  table.className = "tg";
  p.appendChild(table);
    
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
 
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   var outputBox = document.createElement("output");
   var inputBox = document.createElement("input");
  
   tableBody.appendChild(tr);
 
   var td = document.createElement('TD');
    if ( i === 0 ) {
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Total M3 All Rooms:"));
    } else if ( i == 1 ) {
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Extra House Heat Load:"));
    } else if ( i == 2 ) {
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Total System m3 Required:"));
    }
   tr.appendChild(td);
  
   var td = document.createElement('TD');
    if ( i === 0 ) {
     outputBox.id = "HouseM3Total";
     td.appendChild(outputBox);
    } else if ( i == 1 ) {
     inputBox.type = "number";
     inputBox.id = "HouseHeatLoad";
     inputBox.value = "1.0";
     inputBox.step = "0.1";
     inputBox.min = "1.0";
     inputBox.max = "1.3";
     td.appendChild(inputBox);
    } else if ( i == 2 ) {
     outputBox.id = "HouseAdjustM3Total";
     td.appendChild(outputBox);
    }

      tr.appendChild(td);

  }
}
 
function drawTable3() {
 
 var div = document.getElementById("dropper");
 
 //create table
 var drawTable = document.createElement("table");
  drawTable.id = "dropperTable";
  drawTable.className = "tg";
  div.appendChild(drawTable);

 var table = document.getElementById("dropperTable");  
  
 //Create Head Elements
 for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
  var createHead = document.createElement("th");
   if ( i === 0) {
    createHead.innerHTML = "";
   } else if ( i === 1) {
    createHead.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Size";
   } else if ( i === 2) {
    createHead.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Capacity";
   }
   table.appendChild(createHead);
 } 

 for ( var i = 0; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
 
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var dropperName = document.createElement("output");
   dropperName.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Side " + [i + 1];
   cell1.appendChild(dropperName);  

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var dropperInput = document.createElement("input");
   dropperInput.type = "number";
   dropperInput.id = "D" + [i] + "Size";
   cell2.appendChild(dropperInput);
  
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var dropperOutput = document.createElement("output");
   dropperOutput.id = "D" + [i] + "Capacity";
   cell3.appendChild(dropperOutput); 
 
 }
 
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var designCapacity = document.createElement("output");
   designCapacity.colSpan = "2";
   designCapacity.innerHTML = "Design Dropper Capacity";
   cell1.colSpan = "2";
   cell1.appendChild(designCapacity);
   
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var DTotalCapacity = document.createElement("output");
   DTotalCapacity.id = "DTotalCapacity"; 
   cell2.appendChild(DTotalCapacity);
 
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var modelCapacity = document.createElement("output");
   modelCapacity.innerHTML = "Model Dropper Capacity";
   cell1.colSpan = "2";
   cell1.appendChild(modelCapacity);
   
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var dropperCapacityUnit = document.createElement("output");
   dropperCapacityUnit.id = "dropperCapacityUnit";
   cell2.appendChild(dropperCapacityUnit);

 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var modelSelect = document.createElement("output");
   modelSelect.innerHTML = "Model Selection";
   cell1.colSpan = "2";
   cell1.appendChild(modelSelect);
   
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var model = document.createElement("output");
   model.id = "model";
   cell2.appendChild(model);     


}
 
function startCalculate() {
  
  getLocationValue = 0;
  totalHouseM3 = 0;

  findLocation();
  calculateTotalM3();
  calculateDuctDia();
  findUnitSpecs();
  
  return;
}

function dropperCalculate() {

  calculateDropperDia();
  finalUnitCalc();
}

function replaceWithDropdownModel( id , valueList ){
    var element = document.getElementById( id );
    var dropdown = document.createElement("select"),
        value = element.value,
        option;
    dropdown.id = id;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < valueList.length ; i++ ){
        option = document.createElement("option"); 
        option.text = valueList[i];
        option.value = valueList[i];
        if( option.value == value){
          option.selected = true;
          
        }
        dropdown.options.add(option);
    }
    element.parentNode.replaceChild( dropdown , element );
}

function findLocation() {
 var getLocationFactor = document.getElementById("location").value;
 
 for ( var i = 0 ; i < result.locations.length ; i++) {
  if (result.locations[i].name === getLocationFactor) {
  getLocationValue = result.locations[i].factor;
  } 
 }
}

function calculateTotalM3() {

 for ( var i = 0; i < rooms ; i++ ) {

 var roomL = document.getElementById("R" + i + "L").value,
  roomW = document.getElementById("R" + i + "W").value,
  roomH = document.getElementById("R" + i + "H").value,
  roomFactor = document.getElementById("R" + i + "Factor").value,
  ductDia = document.getElementById("R" + i + "Dia"),
  calcM3 = Math.round((roomL * roomW * roomH) * roomFactor);
  
 var outputRoomM3 = document.getElementById("R" + i + "M3Total");
  outputRoomM3.innerHTML = calcM3;
  
  totalHouseM3 = totalHouseM3 + calcM3;
   
 var inputHouseHeatLoad = document.getElementById("HouseHeatLoad").value;
 var outputHouseM3 = document.getElementById("HouseM3Total");
  outputHouseM3.innerHTML = totalHouseM3 + " m3";
  
  for ( var x = 0; x < result.ductInfo.length; x++) {
   if (calcM3 >= result.ductInfo[x].roomDuctSizeLoc1 && calcM3 <= result.ductInfo[x + 1].roomDuctSizeLoc1 && getLocationValue === 1) {
    ductDia.innerHTML = result.ductInfo[x].ductSize;
   } else if (calcM3 >= result.ductInfo[x].roomDuctSizeLoc2 && calcM3 <= result.ductInfo[x + 1].roomDuctSizeLoc2 && getLocationValue === 2) {
    ductDia.innerHTML = result.ductInfo[x].ductSize;
   } else if (calcM3 >= result.ductInfo[x].roomDuctSizeLoc3 && calcM3 <= result.ductInfo[x + 1].roomDuctSizeLoc3 && getLocationValue === 3) {
    ductDia.innerHTML = result.ductInfo[x].ductSize;
   } else if (calcM3 >= result.ductInfo[x].roomDuctSizeLoc4 && calcM3 <= result.ductInfo[x + 1].roomDuctSizeLoc4 && getLocationValue === 4) {
    ductDia.innerHTML = result.ductInfo[x].ductSize;
   } else if (calcM3 >= result.ductInfo[x].roomDuctSizeLoc5 && calcM3 <= result.ductInfo[x + 1].roomDuctSizeLoc5 && getLocationValue === 5) {
    ductDia.innerHTML = result.ductInfo[x].ductSize;
   }   
  }   

 }
 var totalHouseM32 = Math.round(totalHouseM3 * inputHouseHeatLoad);
  
 var outputAdjHouseM3 = document.getElementById("HouseAdjustM3Total");
  outputAdjHouseM3.innerHTML = totalHouseM32 + " m3";
}

function calculateDuctDia() {

 for ( var i = 0; i < rooms ; i++ ) {

 var outletSize = document.getElementById("R" + [i] + "OutletSize").value;
 var outputDuctSize = document.getElementById("R" + [i] + "DuctSize");
 var diaResult;
 
  for ( var x = 0; x < result.ductInfo.length ; x++) {
   if (result.ductInfo[x].ventSize == outletSize) {
    diaResult = result.ductInfo[x].ventSize;
   }
  }
 
 outputDuctSize.innerHTML = diaResult; 
 }
}

function findUnitSpecs() {

 unitArray = [];
 
 for ( var x = 0 ; x < result.modelFinder.length; x++) {
  if (totalHouseM3 <= result.modelFinder[x].location1Capacity && getLocationValue === 1) {
  unitArray.push(result.modelFinder[x].model);
  } else if (totalHouseM3 <= result.modelFinder[x].location2Capacity && getLocationValue === 2) {
  unitArray.push(result.modelFinder[x].model);
  } else if (totalHouseM3 <= result.modelFinder[x].location3Capacity && getLocationValue === 3) {
  unitArray.push(result.modelFinder[x].model);
  }  else if (totalHouseM3 <= result.modelFinder[x].location4Capacity && getLocationValue === 4) {
  unitArray.push(result.modelFinder[x].model);
  }  else if (totalHouseM3 <= result.modelFinder[x].location5Capacity && getLocationValue === 5) {
  unitArray.push(result.modelFinder[x].model);
  }

  replaceWithDropdownModel( "model" , unitArray);
 }
 
 return [
 unitArray
 ];
 
}
 
function calculateDropperDia() {
  
  totalDropperCapacity = 0;
  dropperSides = 6;
  
 for ( var i = 0; i < dropperSides ; i++ ) {

  var dropperSize = document.getElementById("D" + i + "Size").value,
   outputDropperCapacity = document.getElementById("D" + i + "Capacity");
  var dropperResult;
 
   for ( var x = 0; x < result.ductInfo.length ; x++) {
    if (result.ductInfo[x].ductSize == dropperSize) {
     dropperResult = result.ductInfo[x].dropperCapacity;
    } else if (dropperSize > 551) {
     dropperResult = "Size Does Not Exist";
    }
   
   }

  outputDropperCapacity.innerHTML = dropperResult; 
 
  var dropperCapacityElement = document.getElementById("DTotalCapacity");
  totalDropperCapacity = totalDropperCapacity + dropperResult;
 
  dropperCapacityElement.innerHTML = totalDropperCapacity; 
 }
}

function finalUnitCalc() {
  
 var selectedUnit = document.getElementById("model").value,
  dropperCapacityUnit = document.getElementById("dropperCapacityUnit");
 
 for ( var i = 0 ; i < result.modelFinder.length ; i++) {
   if (selectedUnit === result.modelFinder[i].model) {
   dropperCapacityUnit.innerHTML = result.modelFinder[i].dropperCapacity;
   }
 }
}


window.onload = init;


function calculateRoomM3() {
 
 // iterate through all current rows and get the values of each, save it as a variable in each and then calculate
 //
 var table = document.getElementById("calcTable");  
 var rowCount = table.rows[0].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
 console.log(rowCount);
 
// var roomL = 
//  roomW = 
//  roomH = 
//  roomFactor = 
//  roomTotal = 
  
  
// var thisID = document.getElementById(thisID).value,
  //thisW = document.getElementById(thisW).value,
  //thisL = document.getElementById(thisL).value,
  //thisFactor = document.getElementById(thisFactor).value,
  //thisTotal = document.getElementById(thisTotal);
  
 //var roomM3 = Math.round((thisL * thisW * thisID)) * thisFactor;
  
  //thisTotal.innerHTML = roomM3;
  
  //console.log(thisID);
  //console.log(thisW);
  //console.log(thisL);
  //console.log(roomM3);
  
}
```

```css
#calc{
 width: 850px;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

div {
 border: 1px solid white;
}
#dropper {
 width: 400px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 875px;
}
#total {
 clear: both;
}
#button2 {
 position:absolute;
 margin-left: 875px;
 margin-top: -250px;
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
}
p {
 text-align: center;
}
input {
 text-align: center;
}
.tg  {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing:0;
 text-align: center;
 }
.tg td{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:10px 5px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-break:normal;
 text-align: center;
 }
.tg th{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:10px 5px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-break:normal;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
.tg .tg-s6z2{
 text-align:center
 }
.smallInput {
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 }
.factors {
text-align: center;
width: 80px;
}
.factors2 {
text-align: center;
width: 150px;
}
.tg2 {
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 border-top-color: #FFF;
 border-right-color: #FFF;
 border-bottom-color: #FFF;
 border-left-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="ComCool.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <div id="dropper">
        <h1>Dropper Duct Calculator</h1><br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="calc">
        <h1>Calculator</h1>

        <p>Location: <select id="location">
            </select></p>
    </div>
</form>


    <div id="total"></div>
<br/>
<div id="button2">
    <input onclick="startCalculate()" type="button" value=
    "1. Calculate M3, Diameter (Suggested and Actual)">
<br/></br>
    <input onclick="dropperCalculate()" type="button" value=
    "2. Calculate Dropper"><br>
 </div>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Links may change or be removed, making your question invalid and of no future help to anyone. Please post the necessary code here in the question as well as linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for now by getting the entire ID of the current cell the event runs from, then splicing to get the ID scheme that I have through the table.

```
    var str = this.id,
    slice = str.slice(0,2),
    roomL = slice + "L",
    roomW = slice + "W", 
    roomH =  slice + "H",
    roomFactor =  slice + "Factor",
    roomTotal = slice + "M3Total",
    roomDuctDia = slice + "Dia",
```

Its a quick solve, but it works!